# how to loop a increasing container in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to loop a increasing container, for example, if the container is `std::vector`. i need to push_back when looping the vector elements.

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 3,5, 7,9};
for (auto i : v) {  // v is std::vector
  if (i % 2 == 1) v.push_back(i + 1);  // just a demo, the push_back will happen in some condition, won't be a endless loop
  printf("%d ", i);
} // the expected result is : 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
```

I know vector is not the correct container, is there any good tools can handle this?

Comment: what is the expected result of this loop? That it adds elements to `v` until infinity?  Or that it adds a copy of all elements in `v` to `v` ? Neither of this requires this loop

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re asking. You want an arbitrarily-sized list?

Comment: if you have code that is not doing what you expect it to do you should post a [mcve] and explain what you expect it to do. The example you posted is unclear.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number the push_back only happens when some conditions are satisfied, it wont be an endless loop

Comment: please show the code. Broken code alone is not sufficient to describe what it is supposed to do, because it is just broken. Why did you write the loop? What is in the vector before, waht should be in the vector after it?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number ok, thanks for reminding, had edited with demo.

Comment: @nothingisme sounds like you should create another container, loop over the original one, and decide conditionally to copy from the original one and maybe append additional ones.

Comment: Funny how printf keeps popping up in C++. Use std::cout (and if you can std::format). PS vector is a good container for this. But where are your even numbers in your code?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, but the push_back may happens in the second container, too. like a recursion, but it's a endable recursion

Comment: you should also include expected and actual output in the question. I know that the code is wrong, but this information should be in the quesiton. `push_back` (potentially) invalidates iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use iterators or a range based for loop because of reallocation. But there's nothing wrong with the old-school approach of using an index. That's immune to reallocation

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    if (v[i] % 2 == 1)
        v.push_back(v[i] + 1);
    printf("%d ", v[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, as [463035818_is_not_a_number said in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75352551/how-to-loop-a-increasing-container-in-c#comment132960886_75352551), `push_back()` can (potentially) invalidates iterators. (for example, it can make `std::vector` to re-reallocate).

A much simpler solution is to use a `for` loop instead:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 3,5, 7,9};
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) 
    { 
        if (v[i] % 2 == 1) 
        {
            v.push_back(v[i] + 1);
        }
        std::cout << v[i] << ' ';
    }
}
```

[Link](https://godbolt.org/z/7zhPrxnfK).

Answer (score 0):

`push_back` invalidates iterators when the vector has to reallocate. You can resevere enough space and use an iterator based loop:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::vector<int> v = {1, 3,5, 7,9};
    v.reserve(v.size()*2);
    auto begin = v.begin();
    auto end = v.end();
    for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
        if (*begin % 2 ==1) v.push_back(*begin + 1);
    }
    for (const auto& e : v) std::cout << e << " ";
}
```

This assumes that you only need to iterate the elements that were already in the vector before the loop. (Your code assumes that the loop iterates also the newly added ones, but the condition is such that this is not necessary. You need a second loop for printing then.)

Alternatively you could use an index based loop:

```
  auto s = v.size();
  for (size_t i=0; i < s; ++i) {
      // ....
```